# unable to load xml from external file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm trying to load external xml using the following code but it is not working

```
$( document ).load( "data.xml", function(  response, status, xhr ) {        
    console.log( xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  });
```

I have both `data.xml` and `js` file in same folder.

In *chrome* it returns **`404 error`**.

In *FF* it retuns **`0 [Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"`**.

I couldn't understand why this happens?  Please shed some light on this issue.

**Updates:** I gave a shot using **`$.get()`** as mentioned below but still no success.

Meanwhile I also gave a try using pure js like below

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)    {
      xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else {
      xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}
    xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("data.xml");
    console.log(xmlDoc);
```

Still facing errors.

> ***Error in FF:*** NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied [Break On This Error]
>
> xhttp.send();

and

> ***Error in chrome:*** XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/admin/Desktop/public_html%281%29/public_html/data.xml.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. xml.js:13 Uncaught
>   NetworkError: A network error occurred.

**Updates:**
I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653825/error-access-to-restricted-uri-denied) useful, but is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: `$( document ).load( "data.xml"` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: First, you almost certainly want to use `.get()` and not `.load()` here.

Comment: @KevinB Then do I need to use any element?  for example `$('#someid').load(..`  please correct me if I meant wrong?

Comment: @Pointy I tried using `.get()` but it is not logging console messages.

Comment: I hope you're using a local webserver to test this. Looking at your console error outputs I see you're trying to get a file from the `file://` protocol when it should be a relative path from the root folder which then uses `http://` protocol.

Comment: @TimVermaelen Just now figured out the problem, please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19866904/1671639)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(response, status, xhr){
           console.log( xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
        }
     });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449716/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-but-its-not-cross-domain)

Comment: I tried it but it is not working.  I'm not getting any consoles messages.

Comment: Nope, this is not working.  Same behavior but to see for error I tried `$.ajax({
        url: 'data.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(response, status, xhr){
           console.log( xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
        },
  error: function (response, status, xhr){
           console.log( xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
        }
     });` Now it logs `undefined undefined` means still error.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan Doing it the way you're currently doing it doesn't work either does? the way in this answer is far more correct than what you're currently doing. You should use this answer and add an error callback, then console.log the three arguments from the error callback. Most likely the xml is invalid.'

Comment: The third parameter of error: is not an xhr, it's a string. therefore of course you're getting undefined. Log it whole.

Comment: @KevinB I tried whole like `error: function (response, status, err){
           console.log( err );
        }` but only empty log prints.

Comment: Make sure your `xml` is valid by running it through a validator like [this one](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/)

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan that's ok, just means jQuery didn't produce an error reason. Next log the status, and the response.responseText

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for giving me clear understanding, but it both returns `"error" and status: 404`

Comment: @zgood I validated the xml it returns `No errors were found `.  That's a good point, now I tried with whole system path it returns `statusText: "NetworkError: A network error occurred."`

Comment: Move your `data.xml` file to your root from your `js` folder. Or change your `ajax` `url` parameter to `js/data.xml` or whatever your `js` folder is called and located

Comment: @zgood I already have like that.  This has be mentioned in the question.

Comment: Are you executing your javascript from a page or is it in a separate `js` file?

Comment: if you are gettign 404, then the path to your xml is wrong. there is no other reason to get a 404.

Comment: @KevinB I even tried giving the full path but [no success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865938/unable-to-load-xml-from-external-file-using-jquery#comment29549162_19866002)  I have also updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a post that may clarify your issue

Comment: @zgood +1 Thanks for you effort, I have [resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19866904/1671639) the issue.  Feeling of being so stupid.  Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: No problem. We have all been there ;)

Answer (score 1):

After a long struggle and with the help of community I figured out the issue.

> The same-origin policy restricts how a document or script loaded from
>   one origin can interact with a resource from another origin.

Means this is not possible with the system file, so with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8449770/1671639), I used WAMPServer to run my script and it worked like a charm.

```
 $.get("http://localhost/public_html(1)/public_html/xml/data.xml",
                                     function(  response, status, xhr ) {        
        console.log( response );
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looked at it for 5 mins and saw it right away, setting up a localhost is the way to go with these kind of things ^^