# How do I extract data from xml and post to a div using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am trying to get the title for a twitch.tv stream from an xml file using either jQuery or JavaScript and then post that title to a div (as a section header). The title is found in the `<status>` section of the xml file.

Below the code I currently have which doesn't seem to be working:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.twitch.tv/meta/koibu.xml",
            dataType: "xml",

            success: function(xml) {
                    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
                            $xml = $(xmlDoc);
                    $(xml).find('meta status').each(function(){
                            $('#block').append("<h2>" + $(this).text() + "</h2>");
                    });
            }
    });
});
```

Here is a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m37DJ/) -with my broken script in- to play with.

Edit: solved it using a json call instead of reading xml

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var names = ["koibu"];

            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name": {"life": "{life}","logo": "{logo}","status": "{status}","preview": "{preview}","url": "{url}"}}');

            grabJSON();

            function grabJSON() {
                setTimeout(grabJSON,1000);
                for (index = 0; index < names.length; ++index) {

                    $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + names[index] + "/?callback=?", function (json) {
                        $('#lefttitle').empty(),
                        $('#lefttitle').append("<h2>" + json.status + "</h2>");

                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

This also allows me to set up a nice little array to grab more data from multiple channels if I want to extend it in future.

Comment: What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: @jibsales I'm attempting to append a header with the text from the status section of the xml file to the '#block' div, however this script doesn't work and I have no idea why.


edit: 
for instance the current title of the stream is 'Cartography!'. The desired effect is for the #block to be displaying
    <h2>Cartography!</h2>

Comment: you can't fetch xml data from another site using js without using CORS.

Comment: Do you have access to the XML doc? Because Cross Origins restricts in fiddle

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 1):

If you're not suffering from [*CORS*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), then the actual problem is below

```
$(xml).find('status').each(function(){
    $('#block').append("<h2>" + $(this).text() + "</h2>");
});
```

**`xml`** variable represents the *unparsed XML.*

It has to like

```
$xml = $(xmlDoc);
$xml.find('status').each(function(){
    $('#block').append("<h2>" + $(this).text() + "</h2>");
});
```

I managed to get your XML file, and the `status` tag contains **Monday Mafia!**

Comment: It turns out after some digging that I am suffering from CORS, do you know a simple way of circumventing this?

Comment: @CameronGuthrie Simple way!! if the datatype is a JSON, then changing the `dataType` to `jsonp` will solve CORS.  But in your case it is not possible.  **SOLUTION:** Only way to host both the html and xml files in same server.  I too had a same problem, check my question http://stackoverflow.com/a/19866904/1671639