# Get xml document with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I'm trying to get a xml document from w3school site in an HTML page using jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({url: "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml",     
    success: function(xml) {
        alert("ok");  
    },
    error: function(request, error, tipo_errore) {
    alert(error+': '+ tipo_errore); }
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The page give me error alert, what's wrong?

Comment: It is called Same Origin Policy Violation

Comment: Because of CORS, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19866904/1671639

Comment: Use [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) .

Comment: So why can I reach http://updates.html5rocks.com content?
I'd like to know if I can do the same with site like www.google.com