# How to access json data from json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-ajax

I am trying to access JSON data from separate json file(in different folder)but it is throwing exception **" No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.  "**

I have my file at root "Index.html".Parallel to this there is a separate folder "JSON" which contains my json file "quotes.json".
My Code is

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#info-page", function () {
    $.getJSON("Json/quotes.json", function (data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            items.push(val);
            alert(data.key);
        });      
    });
});
```

Comment: try to change the extension of the file: .getJSON("Json/quote.html", etc ..

Comment: Your code is suffering [`CORS`(cross domain issue)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).  see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19866904/1671639) or try to use `jsonp` dataType.

Comment: cors doesn't make sense on local paths; use get() instead of getJSON()...

Comment: json file name is quotes.json.Updated it in question

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a json file with name `quotes.json` instead of `quotes.html` and put your json code inside this file.

Comment: Actually, I just follow OP's question which I'm assuming he's testing on the localhost.