# Access to restricted URI denied. Firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 1 HTML Page and 1 js file . I cannot run script in  Firebug on Chrome 
it shows following Error :

> Access to restricted URI denied.

Code is as per tutorial

HTML Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery Example </title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Hide" id="toggle_messege" />
    <p id="messege">
        You see this paragraph
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/toggle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js file

```
$('#toggle_messege').click(function () {
    var value = $('#toggle_messege').attr('value');
    $('messege').toggle('fast');
    if (value == 'Hide') {
        $('#toggle_messege').attr('value', 'Show');
    }
    else if (value == 'Show') {

        $('#toggle_messege').attr('value', 'Hide');
    }
});
```

Similar post :
[Error: "Access to restricted URI denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653825/error-access-to-restricted-uri-denied)

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2008/12/access-to-restricted-uri-denied-code.html

They suggest it is same domain policy issue and solution is to access file from webserver(localhost)

my url is

```
 http://localhost/WebApplication2/js/
```

But couldnot solve the issue ..
plz suggest if something missing

Comment: Do you have a local webserver running? If so, do you have permission to access it?

Comment: Are your JavaScript files in the correct directory? Are you seeing any errors in the browser's console tools?

Comment: yes ...directory and path are right ..i click on "inspect element" to open firebug section... console section is blank

Comment: Got it ...
changed 

     src="~/js/toggle.js"

to


    src="http://localhost/WebApplication2/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"
    
It worked

Comment: Yeah, the console should have shown you the error about jQuery being undefined or $ being undefined as well as a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your code

1.Change the order of file , jquery reference is first

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/toggle.js"></script>
```

2.You code must be wrapped in `$(document).ready()` and it should be in `<head>` block

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#toggle_messege').click(function () {
    var value = $('#toggle_messege').attr('value');
    $('#messege').toggle('fast'); // You missed # in this line
    if (value == 'Hide') {
        $('#toggle_messege').attr('value', 'Show');
    } else if (value == 'Show') {

        $('#toggle_messege').attr('value', 'Hide');
    }
});
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pG99u/)

Comment: in js fiddle it is working fine..but still same  same error on browser

Comment: @user3487944 so i think js files not loaded check the path

Comment: changed the path to right one ... src="~/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"..still same error