# HTML/Javascript: Enabling folder access from a subdirectory

Tags: javascript, html, file-permissions, permission-denied, project-settings

I have a simple HTML file with some JavaScript that I would like to run locally (as opposed to deploying to a server). It is embedded inside a larger project whose file structure I would like to maintain. For example, the structure is something like this:

```
project level folder > src folder containing folders & files I would like to probe
                     > separate, non-project util folder > HTML & JS files I would like to run against src
```

I am aware that certain browsers do not allow this for [security reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) (as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653825/error-access-to-restricted-uri-denied)), but since I control all of the files - ***is there a way for the src folder/files to somehow indicate that they will allow the 'separate, non-project util folder' to access them?*** Maybe some kind of project-specific settings somewhere? I am aware that this can be done in server settings, but as I mentioned above I'd like to be able to run it locally without the need for a server.

The JavaScript that is attempting to access the src files uses [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), in case that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

I wasn't able to provide full access exactly this way, but instead I setup a dummy HTML page in the `project level folder` that clicks itself to redirect to the HTML file located in the `separate, non-project util folder`. This allowed me to keep everything but that one, very small file separate but not have issues with file access.