# angularjs Error: Access to restricted URI denied

Tags: angularjs, ibm-cloud

I am using $http.get to consume a REST api from IBM bluemix. However when I run this code

```js
var url = "https://username:pass@cdeservice.mybluemix.net"
var count = '/api/v1/messages/count';
searchQuery = 'hi'
$http.get(url + count + "?q=" + searchQuery)
       .then(onResponse, onError);
```

I receive error 1012 - Error: Access to restricted URI denied. I am running on a server (access from localhost:6000) and I have even tried deploying and receiving the same error. Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing here: [Error: "Access to restricted URI denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653825/error-access-to-restricted-uri-denied)

Basically, many standard server/browser implementations will prevent these types of requests due to the [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) being violated.  Unless you controler the server, you may not be able to get around this issue.